# How to destroy all elements with jQuery UI Tabs?

Tags: jquery, tabs

Without knowing which selector has jQuery UI Tabs binded, is there a way to say when this page loads, destroy all jQuery UI tabs binds?

So something like this in pseudo code $('body *').tabs('destroy');

Comment: It has a defaul class called `ui-tabs`, try to get the elements by it.

Comment: Yup Just do `$('.ui-tabs').tabs('destroy');`

Comment: If you're going to destroy them on page load, why initialize them in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty easy to do:

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sSh8p/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.ui-tabs').tabs('destroy');
});
```

Similarly, you can use classes to find other jQuery UI-enabled elements, such as `.ui-draggable`, `.ui-slider`, etc.

Comment: Crap...I totally forgot it adds its own widget classes to it...thanks for the reminder!